# C++Builder 10.3 completely dysfunctional out-of-the box - GUI windows do not update. Is this just me?

Tags: c++builder

I have just installed Community Edition of Embarcadero C++Builder 10.3, as downloaded from the manufacturer's website. When I run it, the Welcome screen looks OK. Then I press on "Create a new Windows VCL application - C++" link to create a simple "Hello World" GUI project targeted at Windows. After that things fall apart - the windows in the RAD Studio do not update, and the only way to get at least some information out of them is to click on them (see screenshot below). And even then their headers never show up. Main toolbar is entirely lost. Main menu is only visible when you click on it. And then the main menu becomes frozen for several minutes. I can't even get to just placing a simple button on the form, let alone writing some code.

I used to be a huge fan of Delphi 20 years ago, did a lot of software development in it, then migrated to MSVC. Now I am trying to migrate back to Delphi/C++Builder tools, so I gave it it a try. But come on, it can't fall apart right after the installation while attempting "Hello World" project! Not a development tool that has decades of history! Am I doing something completely wrong? I really want this tool to work out for me, I have lots of respect for it from 20 years ago.

[image: RAD Studio windows do not update]

Comment: That is 10.3 version. I believe its a known bug and should be fixed in 10.4. I would recommend you try and install 10.4 trial (no community edition of 10.4 at the moment) and see if you still have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I installed C++ Builder 10.3.3 community and opened an example VCL project "Searchbox".
It compiled and ran the program, but I am not able to navigate in the sourcecode.
If I hover the mouse over a datatype or variable, a tooltip appears "cannot find **C:/Users/Public/Documents/Embarcadero/Studio/20.0/Samples/CPP/VCL/SearchBox/usearchbox.cpp**" This is the file in the editor and it definitely exists, however note the path is written with **forward slashes**, this might be the reason of failure.
If I search for declarations via menu, nothing happens, no result, no error.

To me, this seems to be (partially) broken out of the box.
My OS is Win10Pro 64 Bit.
Edit:
This apparently only happens when the classic Borland compiler is deselected which means CLang is used.
Because I am only interested in the CLang compiler, the product is -unfortunately- unusable for me.